# object3D morph targets invisible

Tags: three.js

When i put an object to scene, re-size him by morph targets like in this example:

https://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/examples/webgl_morphtargets.html

when i move camera out of the original size of object, but still looking on re-sized parts, object is disappear.

That means, when i stretch box 100 times, i still need to look on his original center, when i look only on his re-sized part, it becomes invisible.

**Do you have any experience with this behavior?**

**How can i set the object to be visible of full length?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meshes are frustum-culled based on their "un-morphed" geometry.

You can prevent a mesh from being frustum-culled by setting:

```
mesh.frustumCulled = false;
```

three.js r.68

Comment: WestLangley i will propose You for the Nobel Prize, for your answers.